# How spring boot works?

Tags: spring-boot

I'm learning this, I have identified the following steps.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

1. We run MyApplication, it goes to the main method.

```
SpringApplication.run(MyappApplication.class, args);
```

2. `SpringApplication.run(PrimaryTarget, args)` This method initializes the Application context and returns running ApplicationContext.
3. Then ApplicationContext scan primaryTarget, here `MyApplication.class` for Annotations.
4. It sees the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation in the `MyApplication.class`
5. `@SpringBootApplication` = `@Configuration` + `@EnableAutoConfiguration` + `@ComponentScan`
6. `@EnableAutoConfiguration` starts autoconfig based on `@ConditionalOnClass` whether JPA or Kafka class files are present in the classpath, if present then autoconfigure else not
7. `@ComponentScan` scan in the src directory for annotation present in the class, if present make Bean and make it available in application Context.

Is this correct? If not please correct me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mostly correct.

Understanding the implementation of `run` method should clarify all steps.

```java
public ConfigurableApplicationContext run(String... args) {
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    DefaultBootstrapContext bootstrapContext = this.createBootstrapContext();
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = null;
    this.configureHeadlessProperty();
    SpringApplicationRunListeners listeners = this.getRunListeners(args);
    listeners.starting(bootstrapContext, this.mainApplicationClass);

    try {
        ApplicationArguments applicationArguments = new DefaultApplicationArguments(args);
        ConfigurableEnvironment environment = this.prepareEnvironment(listeners, bootstrapContext, applicationArguments);
        this.configureIgnoreBeanInfo(environment);
        Banner printedBanner = this.printBanner(environment);
        context = this.createApplicationContext();
        context.setApplicationStartup(this.applicationStartup);
        this.prepareContext(bootstrapContext, context, environment, listeners, applicationArguments, printedBanner);
        this.refreshContext(context);
        this.afterRefresh(context, applicationArguments);
        Duration timeTakenToStartup = Duration.ofNanos(System.nanoTime() - startTime);
        if (this.logStartupInfo) {
            (new StartupInfoLogger(this.mainApplicationClass)).logStarted(this.getApplicationLog(), timeTakenToStartup);
        }

        listeners.started(context, timeTakenToStartup);
        this.callRunners(context, applicationArguments);
    } catch (Throwable var12) {
        this.handleRunFailure(context, var12, listeners);
        throw new IllegalStateException(var12);
    }

    try {
        Duration timeTakenToReady = Duration.ofNanos(System.nanoTime() - startTime);
        listeners.ready(context, timeTakenToReady);
        return context;
    } catch (Throwable var11) {
        this.handleRunFailure(context, var11, (SpringApplicationRunListeners)null);
        throw new IllegalStateException(var11);
    }
}
```

Further study

- [What Happens Internally When You Start A Spring Boot Application](https://medium.com/javarevisited/what-happens-internally-when-you-start-a-spring-boot-application-part1-a683a64c1be8)